# missing return type compile error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have a `toString` method with a bunch of nested `if` statements. I think I have everything right but I'm getting a "missing return statement" error. Anyone can see why? Thanks.

```
public String toString() //to tell the user what card/s they have
//c.toString()
{
    //for printing?//
//  ArrayList<String> forPrint = new ArrayList<String>();
    getSuit();
    getValue();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if(suit == 1)
        {
            if(value == 11)
            {
                return "Jack of Clubs";
            //  forPrint.add("Jack of Clubs");
            }
            else if(value == 12)
            {
                return "Queen of Clubs";
            //  forPrint.add("Queen of Clubs"); 
            }
            else if(value == 13)
            {
                return "King of Clubs";
            //  forPrint.add("King of Clubs");  
            }
            else if(value == 1)
            {
                return "Ace of Clubs";
            //  forPrint.add("Ace of Clubs")    
            }
            else
            {
                return value + " of Clubs";
            //  forPrint.add(value + " of Clubs");
            }   
        }

        else if(suit == 2)
        {
            if(value == 11)
            {
                return "Jack of Diamonds";
            //  forPrint.add("Jack of Diamonds");   
            }
            else if(value == 12)
            {
                return "Queen of Diamonds";
            //  forPrint.add("Queen of Diamonds");  
            }
            else if(value == 13)
            {
                return "King of Diamonds";
            //  forPrint.add("KIng of Diamonds");   
            }
            else if(value == 1)
            {
                return "Ace of Diamonds";
            //  forPrint.add("Ace of Diamonds");    
            }
            else{
                return value + "of Diamonds";
            //  forPrint.add(value + " of Diamonds");
            }
        }

        else if(suit == 3)
        {
            if(value == 11)
            {
                return "Jack of Hearts";
            //  forPrint.add("jack of Hearts"); 
            }
            else if(value == 12)
            {
                return "Queen of Hearts";
            //  forPrint.add("Queen of Hearts");
            }
            else if(value == 13)
            {
                return "King of Hearts";
            //  forPrint.add("King of Hearts");
            }
            else if(value == 1)
            {
                return "Ace of Hearts";
            //  forPrint.add("Ace of Hearts");
            }
            else
            {
                return value + "of Hearts";
            //  forPrint.add(value + " of Hearts");
            }
        }

        else if(suit == 4)
        {
            if(value == 11)
            {
                return "Jack of Spades";
            //  forPrint.add("Jack of Spades"); 
            }
            else if(value == 12)
            {
                return "Queen of Spades";
            //  forPrint.add(   
            }
            else if(value == 13)
            {
                return "King of Spades";
            }
            else if(value == 1)
            {
                return "Ace of Spades";
            }
            else
            {
                return value + "of Spades";
            }
        }
        else{
            return "none";
        }       //this will never happen

    }

}
```

Comment: well, if you use Eclipse then it will fix it for you: just mouse over the compile error and then click `add return statement`...

Answer (score 2):

Put

```
return "none";
```

in the end of the method.

Comment: But I already did. I thought if I put another "return 'none'" at the very end, it would actually return it.

Comment: You have to take care of each and every possible condition of return statement. *What about if program doesn't enter in loop or no condition is matched.*

Comment: Compiler is not so intelligent that it will evaluate a condition at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put it there instead

```
        //else{
        //    return "none";
        //}       //this will never happen

    }
    return "none"; //Guess it won't happen too
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd simplify your logic into a method, and use a `StringBuilder`, something like -

```
public static String getCardName(int value, int suit) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  if (value == 1) {
    sb.append("Ace");
  } else if (value == 11) {
    sb.append("Jack");
  } else if (value == 12) {
    sb.append("Queen");
  } else if (value == 13) {
    sb.append("King");
  } else {
    sb.append(value);
  }
  sb.append(" of ");
  if (suit == 1) {
    sb.append("Clubs");
  } else if (suit == 2) {
    sb.append("Diamonds");
  } else if (suit == 3) {
    sb.append("Hearts");
  } else {
    sb.append("Spades");
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one possibility where not of the if-blocks execute. And that is the reason of this "Missing return type" compile error. What happens if the control never enters the `for`-loop. To fix this, and a `return` statement next to where the `for`-loop ends.